# How can I delete Azure Jobs by Azure Runbook?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-scheduler, azure-runbook

I'm writing one **Azure Runbook** that must clean montly my test environment.

I need delete some Azure Jobs but when I try to retrieve my jobs with *Get-AzureRmSchedulerJob* command I obtain this error:

```
Get-AzureRmSchedulerJob -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -JobCollectionName myJobCollectionName

Get-AzureRmSchedulerJob : The term 'Get-AzureRmSchedulerJob' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 

script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 

correct and try again.

At line:10 char:1

+ Get-AzureRmSchedulerJob -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureRmSchedulerJob:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I retrieve my jobs inside Azure Runbook? Using PowerShell this command works.
I need cycle all jobs because I cannot delete all jobs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I retrieve my jobs inside Azure Runbook? Using PowerShell this command works. I need cycle all jobs because I cannot delete all jobs.

Powershell command  `Get-AzureRmSchedulerJob` is in the [AzureRM.Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.scheduler/?view=azurermps-5.1.1).
According to exception `The term 'Get-AzureRmSchedulerJob' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,` I assume that there is no [AzureRM.Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.scheduler/?view=azurermps-5.1.1) in your automation account modules.

By default, it is not in Automation. You could check it from azure portal.

**Note:** Dependencies: **AzureRM.Profile (≥ 4.0.0)**. If AzureRM.Profile (<4.0.0) you need to **update the AzureRM.Profile before import AzureRM.Scheduler**

[image]

If it is not in the modules. We could install it manually.

[image]
[image]